# Excel time lapse when date and time is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I need to calculate the time lapsed between 2 cells in a spreadsheet.  Both date and time are entered in the cells M2(5/20/13 2:00 PM) & J2(5/21/13 3:59pm).  I need the result to show how many hours have passed between J2 and M2.  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

I think `=(J2-M2)*24` should suit, as your data seems to be in time format (ie stored as a number of days since Excel chooses to go back plus a fraction of a day - hence times 24.)